# Is Fedora Cloud appropriate for testing Linux apps in a virtual machine?

Tags: fedora

I am looking to test a Linux app on Fedora. The [website for Fedora](https://getfedora.org) notes that there are three versions available: Workstation, Server, and Cloud. While I understand that Workstation will definitely fit my needs (and I know Server would be overkill), I am unclear about if [Cloud](https://getfedora.org/en/cloud/) would work for this.

According to the website, Fedora Cloud is

> **Minimal, fast, flexible**
>
> Everything you need, and nothing you don't. The Fedora Cloud Base image is smaller, so you can deploy faster. Then use the universe of services and tools in Fedora to customize, so your cloud is right for you.

Since I only need a VM to test one app, a minimal, fast operating that is smaller sounds like a good deal. However, I'm unfamiliar with some of the other terms discussed on the page (e.g. not sure what Docker containers are), and if it's intended for a different purpose.

Is Fedora Cloud appropriate for testing Linux apps in a virtual machine? Or am I completely misunderstanding the purpose of this flavor of Fedora?

Comment: For a local VM you probably want `server`, which can still be very minimal. Cloud is intended for running on cloud services such as AWS and Azure.

Comment: @jordanm Would you like to turn that into an answer?